# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$kernel' (T_VARIABLE) in the index.php file

Tags: laravel, parsing, error-handling, kernel, cpanel

When I upload my Laravel project to cPanel I get the following error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$kernel' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Please provide Laravel version, PHP version on your server, hosting Provider, Apache/Nginx configuration and every additional information that can help users better understand your scenario.

Comment: Laravel Framework - 6.03   ,    PHP Version 7.3.9, Apache Version 2.4.41

Answer (score 0):

Your php version is too low. Try version 7.0 or later php.

Comment: I'm using PHP version 7.39 on server